# jQuery syntax error: #/

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I am currently using jQuery, Twitter Bootstrap and AngularJS for my web application. I've been trying to do routing, but jQuery keeps giving me `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/time` whenever I try to click on the time tab, or vice versa. I have no idea which is causing this error, except that it is caused by the # sign. I have googled extensively but to no avail. Here is my code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#/main" data-toggle="tab" id="main-tab">Main</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#/time" data-toggle="tab" id="time-tab">Time Reports</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I need to keep the slash as I use it for my AngularJS routing (i.e. `index.html#/main` and `index.html#/time` will load different content in one of my divs).
What could possibly be causing this error?

Comment: As far as i can see you want an anchor - so simply remove the slash, write #main, #time instead of #/main, #/time.

Comment: I am actually using the slash for my angularJS routing, so I can't remove it. ): Edited my post to reflect that.

Comment: You report a syntax error and don't even post the code that triggers it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I did. That block of code is directly responsible for triggering the error. The actual error occurs inside jquery.min.js itself. I have also stated the actual error given in the first paragraph. Thanks to PSL, I have realized that it was caused by a conflict with Twitter Bootstrap's tabbing.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I guess extra slash in the `href` specifying `id` of the target. remove them and it should work fine.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#main" data-toggle="tab" id="main-tab">Main</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#time" data-toggle="tab" id="time-tab">Time Reports</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Bootstrap looks at the href value as id for the target element to be shown as tab content. SO here in this case it would be looking for something with id = `#/time` which doesn't exist.

if you want to keep href intact you can use data-target attribute

```
<a href="#/main" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#main" id="main-tab">Main</a>
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MXUN9/)

Comment: I see. So there is actually a conflict between bootstrap and my links (since I am trying to link via Angular). The alternative is not to use bootstrap to style my navbar then..?

Comment: data-target attribute is what I needed, thanks. I did not see it documented but now I see it in the source code. thanks!

Comment: My problem is not solved, I am using ui-router angular with jquery and bootstrap

Answer (score 4):

This issue appear when using jquery v3.* and bootstrap3, because "#" is no longer a valid selector(
You can fix it by using  instead of  and remove attributes href="#" and data-target="#" for dropdowns.
Looks like this:

```
<button data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">YOUR_CODE</button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="your-class">YOUR_TEXT</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="your-class">YOUR_TEXT</a></li>          
 </ul>
```

For tabs, which using  it's fixing by replace **"#/"** from href with **"#some_your_id"**

Comment: Thanks - this seems to be the issue I was having with jQuery slim 3.2.1 and bootstrap 3.3.7.

Comment: Be careful using javascript in href can be trouble using Content Security Policy (CSP). This is a conflict with JQ 3.x and and old bootstrap function bootstrap-dropdown. i would recommend to use href="#0" or update to the latest bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

I have my case, I past many times regarding this issue, so here I just wanted to share my case,

There was a code like this:

```
   handleTabs: function () {
    //var hash = document.location.hash;
    //var prefix = "tab_";
    //if (hash) {
    //  $('.nav a[href='+hash.replace(prefix,"")+']').trigger('click');
    //}
    //// Change hash for page-reload
    //$(document).on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
    //  window.location.hash = e.target.hash.replace("#", "#" + prefix);
    //});
},
```

I skip those lines and my problem resolved.

It was a conflict with **hashtagh slash** **#/** handling in the page between this code and ui.router angularJS

Answer (score 0):

In this toggling mechanism, `data-toggle="tab"` looks to switch between different tabs. But, in case of using Angular Routing these links to different view files.

I tried `data-toggle="link"` and it worked for me.