# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/ angularjs and jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Following error shown up in my console whenever my page loads.

"Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/about"

My code is as below:

```
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="#/about" title="About Us">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="#/pricing">Pricing</a>
                </li>
```

It shows for all initial instance of . Initially, it shows for #/about as it is first, If I remove about us tab it will show up for pricing page link.

Its not bootstrap tab issue, This are simple navigation only

Routing Code in app.js:

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
    }).when('/account', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/account.html',
    }).when('/terms', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/terms.html'
    }).when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/about.html'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
```

I have debug its issue of bootstrap, bootstrap nav causing this issue: "nav navbar-nav" 
fixes for this is data-target="#" but wants proper work around for this

Comment: What is your JS code related to routes?

Comment: Use `<a ng-href="/about" title="About Us">About</a>`

Comment: Tried that too still same error

Comment: I have debug, it's because of bootstrap, bootstrap navbar="nav navbar-nav"

Answer (score 17):

This is most probably a Bootstrap issue. Try using `data-target`attribute on your links like this

```
<a href="#/about" data-target="#about" title="About Us">About</a>
```

Comment: Its not about modal, or bootstrap component, its just a nav link

Comment: This fixes my issue by adding data-target="#"

Comment: It's ok for all routes **except "/"**: `a(href='#/', data-target='#')`. My route config is the same: `$routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: /views/home/home.html'})`. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I just removed all `data-toggle` attributes and fixed.

Comment: @TRiNE - did it for me too! Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Ok you gotta remove the slash, '`/`' with which your html becomes,

```
<a href="#about" title="About Us">About</a>
```

If you want to keep the slash, '`/`' you gotta use `data-target` attribute as,

```
<a href="#/about" title="About Us" data-target="#about">About</a>
```

More about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785264/jquery-syntax-error)

Comment: Are you referring to tabs? - Its not a bootstrap tab, its a normal link only

Comment: Did you give it a try? Have you placed `<div ng-view=""></div>`??

Comment: Sorry, where do u asked me to put ng-view, it's header and i have used ng-include

Comment: better to use ng-view when you are using routing. You would generally have it in your index.html where you would inject views, goes pretty well with routing to form SPAs. Anyways did you get it fixed?

Answer (score 5):

This issue happens also on angular 2 projects. I just add data-target="#" to the anchor link. It solved my problem.

```html
 <a data-target="#" [routerLink]="['/link']">my link</a>.
```

Comment: am facing the same issue like what you had faced. could pls share sample implementation of your codes

Comment: when i try your solution. router link getting open in new tab instead of same page

Answer (score 1):

This may be a very rare situation, but I've got same error because of some legacy code using Colorbox and `location.hash`.

```
jQuery(function() {jQuery('.content-row .csc-default a').tooltip({placement:'top'});
jQuery('a.gallery').colorbox({
    maxWidth:'95%',
    maxHeight:'95%',
    slideshow:true,
    current:' {current} / {total}',
    opacity:'0.80',
    transition:'none',
    speed:'550',
    slideshowSpeed:'5500',
    overlayClose:true,
    fixed:false,
    escKey:true,
    arrowKey:true,
    loop:true,
    title: function() { return $(this).data('original-title')},
    close:'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>',
    previous:'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>',
    next:'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>',
    slideshowStart:'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>',
    slideshowStop:'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></span>',
    rel: function() { return $(this).data('rel')}
});
if (location.hash) $(location.hash).collapse('show'); //when this line is commented, Angular Route works properly
});
```

Strange thing is that error was happening only when loading page with link to view like `localhost/index.html#/main` or simply reloading page with any view selected.