# What is this error in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #category/article**

```
<a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" ng-href="#category/article" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSix">
```

**angular**

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'templates/mainView.html'
  })
  .when('/category/:cat', {
    templateUrl : 'templates/catView.html',
    controller : 'categoryCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/'
  });
}]);
```

Comment: try this ng-href="#/category/article"

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Syntax+error%2C+unrecognized+expression&oq=Syntax+error%2C+unrecognized+expression&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=angular+ng+href+Syntax+error,+unrecognized+expression)

Comment: @hadiJZ No its not working :(

Comment: Something like ng-href="'#category/article'"

Comment: @LuanSoares I used same only... its not working

Comment: If you don't use an `{{something}}` expression, don't use `ng-href`, use a normal `href`

Comment: My question would be, Is there a special reason you are using `ng-href`? Because your link is `static`, it would work with `href="#/category/artical"`

Comment: Not sure, but this can help http://stackoverflow.com/a/31498474/3375135 (i saw you are using bootstrap). But in your case it's better to use href.

Comment: @JohannesJander  I removed the ng from href .... still the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

The error could be anything... 
this is a wrote a plunker using *routes*, 
I am using *#/category/article* but it works even with *#category/article*. 
Maybe you are missing something else, in your question its not clear where is the view, and if the injections are working.

So you need a view

```
  <div ng-view=""></div>
```

and from the injected controller you can access your parameters
like:

```
$scope.cat = $routeParams.cat;
```

presuming you are using not a static url.

Your link is in the *mainView.html* partial file.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ADpFrmfhcL5ihy44kbff?p=preview)