# Getting an error when linking a subdirectory in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a link on a page on an Angular site.

```
<li><a href="#admin/editCourse" data-toggle="tab">Edit Course Info</a></li>
```

If I try to click it, Javascript (JQuery) throws an error:

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #admin/editCourse
```

The link works fine if it's  just #admin, but adding the slash breaks it. I can't figure out why this won't work, any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Adding #admin/editCourse as a data target does not fix the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/ angularjs and jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31498325/uncaught-error-syntax-error-unrecognized-expression-angularjs-and-jquery)

Comment: get rid of bootstrap.js and use angular-ui-bootstrap which has no jQuery dependency

Comment: also href should be `#/admin/editCourse`

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks, that was the problem. I'm working with a team in Git, and it looks like we accidentally included both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @charlietfl, I had bootstrap.js included as well as angular-ui-bootstrap. Removing the first include fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but give a shot by using $anchorScroll ([Documentation Link.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll))

Answer (score -2):

href takes URL or ID as a value. Since you are using #, it means it is an id. Use only #editCourse assuming editCourse is an id of a element, or provide your element an ID and use #my_id.

check http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp for possible values of href.