# How to set id of JS render template to ionic components?

Tags: angular, ionic2, jsrender

I have a render template like below

this is my component.html

```
    <customcomponent templateID="#templatesample"></customcomponent>

    <script id="templatesample" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <div class="cont-bg">
       <div class="listrightdiv">
           <span class="templatetext">{{>Name}}</span> <span class="designationstyle">{{>Designation}}</span>
           <div class="aboutstyle">
            {{>About}}
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

In my custom component i have to pass the id of the script template 
But I'm unable to pass the value with "#" that throws error message

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ##templatesample

On searching for general solutions, even with anchor tag there was issue with assigning href

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1423

[Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/ angularjs and jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31498325/uncaught-error-syntax-error-unrecognized-expression-angularjs-and-jquery)

I am moving my application from angular 2 to ionic 2, where i face error with using templates.

Is there any restrictions in ionic to use "#" tags?

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you add the code where you are passing the "#" ? also is this ionic v1 or v2?

Comment: No I am using the script template ID, so that it will render list items by looping every items as given in the template format.

Comment: is it restricted to use # in html for ionic 2? @suraj

Comment: it is the same as angular 2..I havent used jsrender.. if `templateID` is a component variable.. you could try `[templateID]="'#templatesample'"`

Comment: @suraj tried like that also. still didn't work so. My problem is only when i use "#" other component variables are working fine