# ANGULARJS: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #!/

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I'm new to AngularJS. I'm trying to set the navigation between links through AngularJS routing . I do everything the manuals says, But I get that error.

I'm  trying to migrate my working code with plain **JavaScript** and **jQuery** to **AngularJS**. The navigation occurs, but it shows several errors of that type in console, like:

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #!/about and

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #!/#%2F!

In my about section I have a jQuery UI accordion, but now in AngularJS it doesn`t work anymore.

I really don't know what's happening and would like to know in order to be able to solve this kind of issues in the future.

This is my little code, please, be nice fellows and help me out figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var app = angular.module("evalApp", ["ngRoute"])

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl : "content.html"                
        })
        .when("/about", {
            templateUrl : "sobremi.html"
        })

    });

})
```

And in the html this is the relevant code:

```
<li><a href="#/!">Inicio</a></li>
<li><a href="#!about">Sobre mi</a></li>
```

I'm loading the separate templates in the div with the `ng-view` directive

Thanks.

Comment: add this: href='/' & href='/about'

Comment: Try like this.. <li><a ng-href="#!">Inicio</a></li>   <li><a ng-href="#!about">Sobre mi</a>

Answer (score 1):

Seems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31498325/uncaught-error-syntax-error-unrecognized-expression-angularjs-and-jquery) question is similar to yours. Their solution was to add `data-target="#"` to the links.